# Android calendar : created an event using intent , but it does not go back to my activity

Tags: android, events, android-intent, insert, calendar

My app starts an intent to call calendar app inserting an events with these codes

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT)
    .setData(Events.CONTENT_URI)
    .putExtra(Events.DTSTART, date.getTime())
    .putExtra(Events.DTEND, date.getTime() + DateUtils.HOUR_IN_MILLIS)
    .putExtra(Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, TimeZone.getDefault().getDisplayName());
    startActivityForResult(intent,EDIT_EVENT_AGENDAUI);
        //startActivity(intent); dosent make any difference
```

As you can see here, it calls a calendar insert page.
but it is weird that it wont go back to my app instead of go back to calendar view
 after i click "Done". I have to click "back" button on screen to return to my app

this is kinda unfriendly

googled a half day
it seems no one gets this problem.

Any ideas? Thanks

PS

1. i am using Android ICS on Virtual Machine
2. if i click "cancel" to quit the page, it acts as i expected -- go back to my app.    This is good, but much more confused me.

Comment: I am facing an issue when I try to discard the calender event from the popup but it does not return to my activity. Can you please help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are experiencing is the correct behavior. I'm not aware of any shortcut for just adding an event without going into the calendar activity, unless there are some public content provider for the calendar.

Especially in ICS the add-event window might just be a Fragment included in the calendar activity, so it makes perfect sense that you see your event after you have clicked save.

Comment: It's not what I would expect but the problem for me is, when you press the back button in the Calendar view, the `requestCode` returned to onActivityResult is 0. Meaning it's an error or the Intent was cancelled.